# String Replacement operations in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, xml-parsing

I got the result which is in the form of

```
<ZmaterialGroupList><Matkl>001</Matkl><Text>Metal processing</Text></ZmaterialGroupList>
```

I need to get the result as 001 Metal processing when i apply the string replacement function upon this it give an exception.Please help me.

Added code from comment:

```
for(int i=0; i<[soapArray.items count]; i++) {
    NSString *str = [soapArray.items objectAtIndex:i];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<Matkl>" withString:@""];
}
```

In this way I wrote but I got an exception like
Invalid argument pass at str

Comment: Please post what code you already have and more examples of the input.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<[soapArray.items count];i++)
    {
        NSString *str=[soapArray.items objectAtIndex:i];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<Matkl>" withString:@""];
     }  In this way I wrote but I got an exception like Invalid argument pass at str

Comment: I put the comment code in the question and re-formatted the question so that the original xml displays correctly.

Comment: How did you populate soapArray? What's in it?

Comment: In your added comment code there the value of str is not being saved. What is the error exactly and on which line is it occurring.

Answer (score 2):

You might do better to use [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) rather than trying to replace pieces of the XML.

If you update your question to include a bit more explaining your code (specifically the code that deals with soapArray), I should be able explain a bit more as to why your code doesn't work as it is.

---

## Using NSXMLParser

It's important to remember that NSXMLParser just reads the data you give it sequentially, it doesn't use a DOM structure.

### Setup

Primarily you need to give your parser something to parse! In my example I get a resource from the bundle and convert it to NSData. There is also however another option to `initWithContentsOfURL`. Make sure you don't forget to set your delegate!

```
-(void) parse
{
    NSString *file = @"myXMLFile.xml";
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[file stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[file pathExtension]]];
    //If you already have a string:
    //NSData* data=[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (data.length == 0)
    {
        //No data
        return nil;
    }

    ...
}

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
```

### Parsing

```
-(void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
   //Here you set up any variables you might need while parsing
}

-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
   //I usually don't have to do anything here but you might need to release some variables here for example.
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    //Here is where the bulk of the parsing is done if you are using attributes. I prefer to use attributes as it looks cleaner both in the XML file and the parser.
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element1"])
    {
        //Just an example of what you might want to do
        int index = [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"attribute1"] intValue];
        NSString *name = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"n"];
        [exampleDictionary setValue:name forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index]];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element2"])
    {
        //We need to know that the next piece of information (from foundCharacters) is for element 2
        currentElement = ELEMENT_2;
    }

}

//If you haven't used attributes you might find that you have a lot of parsing to do here instead.
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{ 
    //Check what this info is for?
    if(currentElement == ELEMENT_2)
    {
        element2Data = [NSString stringWithString:string];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element2"])
    {
        myObject.somethingThatNeedsElement2 = element2;
    }
}
```

### Finishing

After finishing it's a good idea to check that nothing went wrong and free up the parser memory. So in your `parse` method, add this after the call to `[parser parse]`.

```
if ([parser parserError] != nil)
{
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error parsing XML" message:[[parser parserError] localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
}
[parser release];
```

Comment: can u please explain how to use NSXMLParser

Comment: I dont have any xml file but the result I am getting is in xml format then how to parse it

Comment: I've updated my answer. Have a look in the first section of code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an XML parser or you can use `NSScanner`:

Example:

```
NSString *wanted;
NSString *fullMessage;
NSString *xml = @"<ZmaterialGroupList><Matkl>001</Matkl><Text>Metal processing</Text></ZmaterialGroupList>";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:xml];

[scanner scanUpToString:@"<Matkl>" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanString:@"<Matkl>" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"</Matkl>" intoString:&wanted];
fullMessage = wanted;

[scanner scanUpToString:@"<Text>" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanString:@"<Text>" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"</Text>" intoString:&wanted];
fullMessage = [fullMessage stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", wanted];

NSLog(@"fullMessage: '%@'", fullMessage);
```

NSLog output:
fullMessage: '001 Metal processing'

Comment: for(int i=0;i<[soapArray.items count];i++)
    {
        NSString *wanted;
        
        NSString *str=[soapArray.items objectAtIndex:i];
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<Text>" intoString:nil];
        [scanner scanString:@"<Text>" intoString:nil];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"</Text>" intoString:&wanted];
        NSLog(@"wanted: '%@'", wanted);
    
    }

Comment: when I am trying to do  in this way I got an exception as Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',

Comment: The result get into the variable str isstr is : '<ZmaterialGroupList><Matkl>001</Matkl><Text>Metal processing</Text></ZmaterialGroupList>'
but next I got an exception .

Comment: This is an example for parsing a string, that was the initial question. If you are trying to use the example code in a loop you will have to adapt the code and iunsure the strings are valid, that is match the parsing pattern. GIven the looping, this may not be the best way to do the parsing.